# Configure static properties with spring.NET

Tags: .net, spring, spring.net

What are best practices to configure following class with spring.NET?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Edu3.DTOModel;

namespace Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework
{
    public static class RepositoryFactory
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> Repositories = 
            new Dictionary<string, object>();

        static RepositoryFactory()
        {
            Repositories.Add(typeof(ISsoUrlTemplateRepository).Name, 
                new SsoUrlTemplateRepository());
            Repositories.Add(typeof(IPackageSessionNodeRepository).Name, 
                new PackageSessionNodeRepository());
            Repositories.Add(typeof(IPackageSessionNodeFinishedRepository).Name, 
                new PackageSessionNodeFinishedRepository());
        }

        public static IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity, TRepository>()
            where TEntity : IEntity
        {
            var interfaceShortName = typeof(TRepository).Name;

            // The provider was in the cache, so retrieve it
            var repository = (IRepository<TEntity>)Repositories[interfaceShortName];

            return repository;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add the repositories with Spring.NET. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose the dictionary as a public property and remove the readonly modifier of the field and don't make your class static. Then use this configuration:

```
  <object id="RepositoryFactory" type="Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework. RepositoryFactory, Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework">
    <property name="Repositories">
      <dictionary key-type="System.Type" value-type="System.Object">
        <entry value-ref="SsoUrlTemplateRepository">
          <key>
            <expression value="T(Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework.SsoUrlTemplateRepository, Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework)"/>
          </key>           
        </entry>
      </dictionary>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object id="SsoUrlTemplateRepository" type="Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework.SsoUrlTemplateRepository, Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework" singleton="false"/>
```

Comment: Thx, will check this in a moment.

Comment: What does Spring.Net behind the curtain? creating an instance of RepositoryFactory?
Additional I would suggest to make the default constructor private

Comment: Spring.NET creates an instance, so making the default constructor private will make this fail. If you really want to enforce this use a factory method. I'd inject the repository factory in the objects that need to get a reference to a repository.

Comment: I'm using now this approach and it works with a private constructor. I think Spring.Net uses reflection an as long as there is a default constructor the visibility doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with initializing my application because there doesn't seam to exist a way to call static methods on a (static) class in spring.net. But you can try to make your class non-static try following:

```
public class RepositoryFactory
{
    private static RepositoryFactory instance;

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> Repositories =
        new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private RepositoryFactory()
    {
    }

    public static RepositoryFactory GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new RepositoryFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void AddRepository(object repository)
    {
        Repositories.Add(repository.GetType().Name, repository);
    }
}
```

with the spring-config:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" >

  <object id="RepositoryFactory" type="Edu3.Data.SubsonicProvider.RepositoryFramework.RepositoryFactory, %ASSEMBLY_NAME%" factory-method="GetInstance">
    <property name="AddRepository" value="SsoUrlTemplateRepository" ></property>
    <property name="AddRepository" value="PackageSessionNodeRepository" ></property>
    <property name="AddRepository" value="PackageSessionNodeFinishedRepository" ></property>
  </object>

  <object id="SsoUrlTemplateRepository" type="SsoUrlTemplateRepository, %ASSEMBLY_NAME%" singleton="false"/>
  <object id="PackageSessionNodeRepository" type="PackageSessionNodeRepository, %ASSEMBLY_NAME%" singleton="false"/>
  <object id="PackageSessionNodeFinishedRepository" type="PackageSessionNodeFinishedRepository, %ASSEMBLY_NAME%" singleton="false"/>

</objects>
```

Comment: is this a possible solution? or have you found an other solution in the meanwhile which you could share?

Comment: Yes, this is possible solution. I'm still checking another solution. Maybe it's possible with spring expressions... don't know, have to look into it deeper. Will post if I find something.