# Get typeof(...).Name using Spring.NET

Tags: .net, spring.net

Is there a way to get the string representation of an interface using Spring.NET?

In code:

```
typeof(ISsoUrlTemplateRepository).Name
```

I would need this name in Spring.NET configuration... I could just take the string itself but if I would ever refactor and change the names of some interfaces, the Spring configuration wouldn't work anymore.

This relates to another question I've asked --> [Configure static properties with spring.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034374/configure-static-properties-with-spring-net)

Comment: I don't see what "to get the string representation of an interface" has to do with Spring.NET.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433676/ioc-spring-net-injecting-system-type/8438819. In this question a nice summary  is given of different ways to inject type in spring.net using xml config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a typename in your Spring.NET config you need to use Spring Expression language.

Like so:

```
<object id="MyClass" type="Assembly.Type, Assembly">
    <property name ="MyTypeProperty" value="T(AnotherAssembly.AnotherType, AnotherAssembly)"/>        
 </object>
```

Comment: Benny, looks like you've been using Spring.NET a lot. Thx for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
typeof(ISsoUrlTemplateRepository).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Which includes full type name, plus assembly name from which that was loaded.